# is xfs a good raid setup?

Tags: raid, amazon-ec2, software-raid, xfs, raid0

I'm using amazon, and there is docs everywhere to use xfs. Is xfs a software based raid? Is it fast?

Comment: I think I'm using mdadm, is this software or hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XFS is not a RAID implementation. It is a filesystem. It does happen to have some nice tweaking ability. Some of those tweaks increase the performance of the filesystem when used in a RAID array. It is very fast...especially when configured properly. That's probably why Amazon recommends it.

Answer (score 1):

[XFS](http://xfs.org/index.php/Main_Page) is a high performance file system originally developed by SGI.  RAID would have to be done either in hardware or software at a lower level.

Comment: I think I'm using mdadm, is this software or hardware?

Comment: mdadm is software raid.